# enabling expand string resource pop-up in android studio

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

In android studio,the bulb pop-up which was used to expand string resource window is not showing up, i have tried ALT+Enter but nothing is happening,can anyone help me to get that popup back because it was present initially and i could not find it now.thanks in advance

Comment: This also happens to me every once in a while. How i fix it is to move the cursor to the red underline, the lightbulb often pops up. Otherwise just move the cursor using the left or right arrow keys.

Comment: i tried but could not fix this,initially the pop up appeared as soon as i dragged the textbox or any other utility item but it does not appear now even if i move the cursor along the boundary.